# Javascript method which iterates an object's properties

Tags: javascript

I have a question about which method is used to iterate an object's properties.

I have two identical objects.  The first object is `main`, and the second object is `clone`.

There is a lot of nesting. I don't have time to write all of the  `for`, `for in`, `forEach` loops, because there is a lot of nesting.

How can I replace the value of each property of `clone` from `main`?  Does such a method already exist?

Comment: Such a method is not built into Javascript.  You  will have to write your own or find a library that has such a method.

Comment: OK. Do you know some library with this method?

Comment: Use recursion if you can't write out the loops.

Comment: There are such methods readily accessible if you search for "javascript deep copy object".

Comment: I don't need copy object. Just replace current value of other object!

Comment: Asking for a library that does this is considered "off-topic" here on stack overflow and not allowed.

Comment: @Maksim: How is replacing the value of each property of a deeply nested object structure with that from another different from a deep copy?

Comment: Listen to me. 
 I have two objects. First Object is main object. Second Object is clone object. And how can I replace value of each property of clone object to main Object property.

Comment: Listen to me. 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486922/method-witch-iterates-objects-property#comment62470423_37486922

Comment: And what? What have you sent me?

Comment: If the objects are identical, then why do you need to replace any values?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

```
function fillClone(source,target)
{
    if(typeof source == "array" && typeof target != "array")
       target = [];
    else if(typeof source == "object" && typeof target != "object")
       target = {};
    for (var i in source) {  
       if(typeof i == "object" || typeof i == "array")
          fillClone(source[i],target[i]);
       else
          target[i] = source[i];  
    }
    return target;
}
```